# How to always accept a particular branch with github merge

Tags: git, github

I have created two branches and developed them as such:

```
arc_conversion   / () - () - () - () - () \
master           - () - () - ()   (1) -   (2)
onboarding       \ () - () - () /
```

Notice I have numbers 1 and 2 in the tree. The first thing I want to do is merge onboarding to master. Notice that thgere have been a few commits on master. I want to totally disregard these changes and always accept what's in the onboarding branch, but I don't know how to tell git to do this. Is this something a strategy would be useful for? In the past I have gone file by file to read the ">>>>>>>" "<<<<<<<<" tags and erase sections, but I'd really like to avoid that as this is a large project.

git checkout master
git merge (????) onboarding

And then for 2.) I'd like to merge arc_conversion into master, but this will be a standard merge which I feel I can do just fine. If you notice an easier way for me to do this, please ring in.

Thanks

Comment: You want to totally disregard the changes made in master: do you mean you want to remove the commits on master and pick-up from the point at which you created onboarding branch, or do you mean you want to merge and "always chose the onboarding" version whenever there is a merge conflict. These are very different things. I'll post an answer depending on what you want.

Comment: Thank you. I want to do the second option you listed. Merge the branches always choosing the onboarding branch change. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a merging strategy `-X` using `theirs`

Checkout the master branch

```
git checkout master
```

Merge the onboarding branch with the -Xtheirs options:

```
git merge onboarding -Xtheirs
```

Merge arc_conversion next

```
git merge arc_conversion
```

That should do it